# React: Seperate loading button inside post.map() when like/dislike

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-context

I am trying to make like/dislike function in react , Issue I am facing is if I am trying to like / dislike ay post , in every other post(s) like/dislike button is going to loading state. Means I am liking one post but every post like button is loading . They are not doing anything just loading indicating because  `{isLoading ? }` kind of state is there.

This may be I am handling loading state wrong or any other. Please someone help who have any idea what is going wrong?

[image]

If I am trying to like "Hi there!" post . Like button of "Hello" post starts loading.

This is my like button logic :

```
  const [likeHandling, setLikeHandling] = useState(false);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

//This will fetch all posts
  const getAllPost = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axiosjwt.get(`${BASE_API_URL}/get-community-posts`);
      setPosts(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

//This will like or unlike post in this same endpoint and return that particualar post
const likePost = async (post_id, user_id, index) => {
    try {
      setLikeHandling(true);
      const res = await axiosjwt.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/likehandle`, {
        post_id,
      });
      console.log(res.data);
      const updatedPosts = posts.map((post) => {
        if (post._id == res.data._id) {
          return res.data;
        } else {
          return post;
        }
      });
      setPosts(updatedPosts);
      setLikeHandling(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setLikeHandling(false);
    }
  };


<button
                        disabled={likeHandling}
                        className="inline-flex justify-center items-center w-full hover:bg-gray-100 py-1"
                        onClick={() => likePost(post._id, user.User._id, index)}
                      >
                        <span className="mr-2">
                          {post.likes.includes(user.User._id.toString()) ? (
                            <>
                              <button disabled={likeHandling}>
                                {" "}
                                <AiFillLike
                                  className={
                                    likeHandling
                                      ? "w-6 h-6 text-blue-500 animate-bounce"
                                      : "w-6 h-6 text-blue-500"
                                  }
                                />
                              </button>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            <button disabled={likeHandling}>
                              <AiOutlineLike
                                className={
                                  likeHandling
                                    ? "w-6 h-6 text-gray-700 animate-bounce"
                                    : "w-6 h-6 text-gray-700"
                                }
                              />
                            </button>
                          )}
                        </span>
                        <span className="text-md font-bold">
                          {post?.likes ? post.likes.length : 1} Likes
                        </span>
                      </button>
```

Please some one help & suggest if any improvement can be done? Or any other thing required to solve my problem?

Comment: If someone cannot understand what is likeHandling? : likeHandling is kind of isLoading for like/dislike . Tq❤️

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you have only one loading flag for all like buttons. You need loading flag per like button. You should create some `<LikeButton />` component that will have it's own loading state, and then use `<LikeButton />` in .map. You just need to move it one level down, to button level. Also use keys inside `map`.